# Can not create hashtag in Telegram API

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am building Telegram Bot for my channel. I am using `parse_mode=Markdown` to make messages more beautiful.

Also I need to make anchors to provide easier searching. I am trying to do I have integer value `discount['id']` and I am building anchor like this:

```py
telegramPost = '%23' + str(discount['id'])
```

But it prints only how plain text. I also tried to make it like

```py
telegramPost = '[%23' + str(discount['id']) + ']'
```

But it gives the same result. How to make a clickable hashtag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `discount['id']` value. It is impossible to create anchor using only numbers. So I did it like this:

```py
telegramPost = '%23id' + str(discount['id'])
```